# Highcharts export server layout algorithm error

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highcharts export server node module to export treemap charts. I'm trying to create a custom layoutAlgorithm. I already have this working on the client side, but when I move the code to the server I get errors. Here's some example code:

```
import * as exporter from 'highcharts-export-server';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

function quadrants(parent, children) {
    let width = parent.width / 2;
    let height = parent.height / 2;

    let areas = [
        {
            x: parent.x + width,
            y: parent.y,
            width,
            height,
        },
        {
            x: parent.x,
            y: parent.y,
            width,
            height,
        },
        {
            x: parent.x,
            y: parent.y + height,
            width,
            height,
        },
        {
            x: parent.x + width,
            y: parent.y + height,
            width,
            height,
        },
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        areas.push();
    }
    return areas;
}

// This is the problem line
Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.quadrants = quadrants;

const exportSettings = {
  // ...
  series: [
    type: 'treemap',
    levels: [{
      level: 1,
      layoutAlgorithm: 'quadrants',
    }],
  ],
  // ... 
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  exporter.export(exportSettings, (err, res) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(res);
  });
});
```

When I run this code I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'treemap' of undefined
```

Is this the incorrect way to set the layout algorithm or is there another way to set a layout algorithm with the highcharts export server?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a full code of the above module, especially the quadrants function and the rest of the exportSettings? I have used the parts of the provided code and I was able to export the treemap chart correctly.

Comment: @pawel_d I included the quadrants function. The export settings shouldn't matter since it's not even getting to that point. It's dying at `Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap`. Note that this is only for the Node export server. When I run this on the client it works OK. When I debug the imported Highcharts variable in node it doesn't have the same properties that are available on the client.

Comment: The reason why you receive an error is because you didn't load and initialize the treemap module, therefore treemap series cannot be found. Unfortunately, even if you do it, this still won't work as Highcharts here is referring to Highcharts’ npm package which isn't used in the exporting process. The export server uses scripts that are fetched on initial configuration (choosing the CDN to download scripts) and are stored in the ./phantom/export.html file. So if you would like to use this custom algorithm function, you would have to find the way to modify the scripts loaded there.